# HTML: adding <form> tags to in input textbox puts textbox under website logo

Tags: html, css, forms, textbox, navbar

I am making a social network and am having some troubles with my navbar and the search box. I have a simple code for the textbox

```
<div style="float:left">
    <a href="index.php"><div class="website_icon"></div></a>
    <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="Search..." />
</div><
```

When I have the code like this, it looks like this http://prntscr.com/39v9g0

Now

```
<div style="float:left">
    <a href="index.php"><div class="website_icon"></div></a>
    <form action="" method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="q" class="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    </form>
</div>
```

When I add `<form></form>` tags to the textbox, it looks like this http://prntscr.com/39v9kl

Here is my css for the textbox, and for the website_icon

```
/*Search box*/
.search {
    height: 30px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    border: 0px;
}
/*Search box hover*/
.search:hover {
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
/*Search box focus*/
.search:focus {
    outline: none;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    width: 300px;
}
/*Website icon*/
.website_icon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url('../img/desktop-icon.png');
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 7px;
    float: left;
}
```

Does anyone know why the textbox goes under the logo when adding the form tags? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe something to do with vertical alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is `block element`, that is the reason it starts from new line.

Make it `display:inline-block`

```
form{
  display:inline-block
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/neraqemi/4/)**

Answer (score 1):

a `<form>` element is a block-type DOM element by default. And you float the website-icon, but do not float the form itself. Because an `<input/>` element is inline by default, it works fine without the form.

You have two options: float the form as a whole, or just move the icon inside the form (a form can hold pretty much everything, expect other forms). I would go with option two.